# Why all previous SMSs are deleted after receiving a normal SMS on my iPhone4/iOS 7.1.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, sms

I received a normal SMS (GSM SMS, not iMessage) from my friend on my iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.2. There were lots of messages (more than 10K) in that chat thread before the last message received. When I opened that SMS, I saw that there is only one message in that thread. All previous messages were deleted after receiving that SMS.

I tried reopening the Messages application, restarting my iPhone, scrolling up after more messages received, but no luck.

After that, I logged in to my iPhone with SSH and downloaded the SMS db file (~31MB) located in `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db`. I opened the db file with sqlite3, there were 36K SMS/iMessages, but there were no messages before the last message in that thread in the database file.

Is there any reasonable scenario that cause this data loss? How can I recover those deleted messages?

Comment: Can you confirm that your friend didn't change his phone number or add another email to his iMessage account?

Comment: Yes. None of these are occurred. Note that this question is not related to iMessage. It is a GSM/Cellular SMS issue. In the Message application different numbers/accounts will be appeared separately. Other chat threads there have no problems.